# TypeScript | Array.from | error TS2339: Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I was googling, but cannot find the information what and how should I add to my project to allow me using ES6 methods like `Array.from`

__ EDIT: removed prototype word

Comment: 'Array.from' is supported in most browsers, but you can find a [polyfill in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill)

Comment: The question is how to add it to TypeScript definitions... I don't need polyfill, I use Babel and TypeScript to translate my ES6 code to ES5. Just TypeScript has no definition, for newest methods...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily extend existing types like so:

```
interface Array {
    from(arrayLike: any, mapFn?, thisArg?): Array<any>;
}
```

The problem here is that this will add the function to the array instances and not as a static function like you require.
But that can be done like so:

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    from(arrayLike: any, mapFn?, thisArg?): Array<any>;
}
```

Then you should be able to use `Array.from`.

Try it out on [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ArrayConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%09from(arrayLike%3A%20any%2C%20mapFn%3F%2C%20thisArg%3F)%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20Array.from(%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D)%3B).

---

#### Edit

If you need to polyfill the implementation (because the environment in which you intend to run doesn't have it), then this is how:

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    from(arrayLike: any, mapFn?, thisArg?): Array<any>;
}

Array.from = function(arrayLike: any, mapFn?, thisArg?): Array<any> {
    // place code from MDN here
}
```

[The polyfill code in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill).

---

#### 2nd edit

Based on a comment, I'm adding a typed version:

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    from<T, U>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>, mapfn: (v: T, k: number) => U, thisArg?: any): Array<U>;
    from<T>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>): Array<T>;
}
```

It's an exact copy of how it's defined in the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4235).

Comment: Does it mean that there is no "standard" way of adding ES6 methods definitions to TS? I tried to find it here: http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/ but without any luck... Is this next "great" thing, made by MS?

Comment: @Kania What's not standard about it? The language gives you the ability to add methods when needed, what else can you ask for?

Comment: ES6 is not a private project. Why should I add defined by ES6 methods manually? maybe I expect too much from MS.

Comment: There are quite a few things that people would like to be added to typescript, and things are done over time, but you can't expect it to have it all..  But since you can very easily add it yourself, maybe it's not on their top priorities

Comment: If you are using visual studio you can use: Install-Package es6-shim.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

Comment: I've added code snippet that implements this solution in the next answer

Comment: using the interface ArrayConstructor doesn't stop me getting that error.

Comment: also **from(arrayLike: any, mapFn?, thisArg?): Array<any>;** isn't valid:     TS2315: Type 'Array' is not generic.

Comment: @Nikos Sounds like you have a problem with your setup. Ask a new question, reference this thread in it and provide your code and `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: Just as a note you spelled from wrong in the last line, it should be 'from' not ''form'

Comment: @labago Thanks! fixed it.

Comment: This isn't fully typed (I didn't add the `mapFn`'s return type) but you can get the most important bits like so: `from<T>(arr: ArrayLike<T>, mapFn?: (item: T, index: number, array: Array<T>) => any, thisArg?: any): Array<T>;` (only tested in TS 2.2)

Comment: @SandyGifford I added a typed version to my answer. I just copied what's in the `lib.es6.d.ts` file

Comment: Even got the typing on map - nice!  Adding this to my own project right away.

Comment: Although, this would appear to return an array of type `any` if no map function is provided (also `mapfn` is required)

Comment: This is going to be a little hard to read since comments are single-lined, but consider using this interface:  `interface ArrayConstructor { from<T>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>, thisArg?: any): Array<T>; from<T, U>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>, mapfn: (v: T, k: number) => U, thisArg?: any): Array<U>; }`

Comment: @SandyGifford My bad, I forgot to copy the other signature for it (which doesn't include the mapping). I fixed my answer.

Comment: This is polyhacking, while usefull, I think using the correct libraries should be the correct answer. Will change vote if updated

Comment: @vandijkstef the `--lib` option was added in typescript 2 which was released after this answer was posted (sept. 2016)

Answer (score 22):

If you are sure the API exists on your engine at runtime, compile with `--lib es6` (or `--lib dom,es6` if you are using the DOM APIs).

See [Compiler Options documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for more details.

Comment: Please remove the space to make it like this '--lib dom,es6'.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it isnt terribly off topic but I found this while refactoring js to ts, and if you have an array like, it appears to work simply passing the array like to the constructor instead of using from, removing the need for the extra method.

eg

```
// someScript.js

Array.from( arrayLikeThing );
```

becomes

```
// someScript.ts

Array( arrayLikeThing );
```

If there are other reasons to maintain using .from then the above answers are great.

Comment: As a warning, just found out this doesnt compile to array.from, so may be best to jsut reimplement like above

Comment: `Array.from(Array(3)).map(v => 1) // [1, 1, 1]`

Comment: `Array(Array(3)).map(v => 1) // [1]`

Answer (score 0):

added below line to tsconfig.json inside compilerOptions solved for me.

"lib": [ "DOM", "ES2015.Core", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2015.Collection", "ES2015.Iterable", "ES2015" ]